# Custom Route in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I am a newbie at rails, and trying to help troubleshoot an issue.

I need to set up a custom route for guest users to see public content from a specific subdomain.  ie when a guest user goes to subdomain.myapp.com they would see guest content,  if they log in,  they get to see content specific to their role and add content.  So I have built the following routes:

```
match '/', to: "lessons#custom", constraints: { subdomain: 'hbec2' }, via: [:get]

  match '/', to: 'home#index', constraints: { subdomain: 'www' }, via: [:get]
  root :to => "home#index"

  get "welcome" => "lessons#welcome", :as => "welcome"

  constraints subdomain: 'hbec2' do
    resources :home   do
      collection do
        get '/lessons/:lesson_category_id', to: 'lessons#custom', as: 'lessons'
        get "custom"
        get "load_categories"
        get "load_subcategories"
        get "load_child_subcategories"
      end
    end
  end

  constraints subdomain: 'www' do
    resources :home   do
      collection do
        get "sub_categories"
        get "categories" => "lessons#welcome"
        get "welcome"
      end
    end
  end
```

At the moment when users go to hbec2.myapp.com they get the desired result,  as it routes it to my custom function in my lessons controller, and renders my custom.html.erb.  However when they click a link in the custom view,  they are redirected to index.html.erb instead of staying on this view,  which has the partial html to render the results.

What I was hoping is that they would stay on custom.html.erb so i added the additional resource get '/lessons/:lesson_category_id', to: 'lessons#custom', as: 'lessons' in hopes that is what it would be looking for. But no luck.  here is my custom function from the controller and custom view

custom function (the idea is to pull information for the guest user. The guest user belongs to HBEC org  so they log into hbec.myapp.com and get the right results (listing of categories for hbec and most recent lessons for hbec),  when the click on a lesson category it should show them the lessons within that category (the query returns the right result as the lessons are in the most recent,  just when you click category it says there is nothing there), but instead shows them nothing. as it goes to index.html.erb, instead of staying on custom.html.erb

```
def custom
    params[:per_page] = 5
    @organization = Organization.find_by_id(HBEC_ORG_ID)
    @organization_categories = []
    @categories = LessonCategory.all
      @organization_categories = @categories.where("organization_id = #{HBEC_ORG_ID}")  
    @categories = @categories.where("organization_id = #{HBEC_ORG_ID}").limit(15)

    @lesson_category = LessonCategory.find_by_id(params[:lesson_category_id]) unless params[:lesson_category_id].blank?
    @lesson_subcategory = LessonSubCategory.find_by_id(params[:lesson_sub_category_id]) unless params[:lesson_sub_category_id].blank?

    keyword = params[:keyword] unless params[:keyword].blank?
    @lessons = Lesson.scoped
    # @lessons = @lessons.where("is_disable = ? ", false)
      @lessons = @lessons.where("organization_id = #{HBEC_ORG_ID}")


    @lessons = @lessons.where(["lessons.id = ? OR lessons.name LIKE ? ", keyword.to_i, "%#{keyword}%"]) unless keyword.blank?
    @lessons = @lessons.where(["lesson_category_id = ?", params[:lesson_category_id]]) unless params[:lesson_category_id].blank?
    @lessons = @lessons.where(["lesson_sub_category_id = ?", params[:lesson_sub_category_id]]) unless params[:lesson_sub_category_id].blank?

    params[:page] = 1 if params[:page].blank?
    max_pages = (@lessons.count / per_page.to_i).to_i + 1
    params[:page] = max_pages if params[:page].to_i > max_pages
    @lessons = @lessons.order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction + ', lessons.created_at DESC').paginate(:per_page => per_page, :page => params[:page])
    @current_page = params[:page]
    @toal_pages = max_pages
  end
```

custom.html.erb

```
<div class="pages page-work gray-bg medium-grey" id="">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Header -->
    <header>
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="span7 lesson_header">
          <%= render "/lessons/breadcrum" %>

        </div>
        <div class="span5 pull-right lesson_header">
          <%= render "lessons/lesson_header" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <!-- End Header -->


    <!-- Article -->
    <article class="showdetail">


      <div><%= render "shared/flash_messages" %></div>
              <%= render "/organizations/organization_categories", :organization => @organization, :organization_categories => @organization.lesson_categories %>
    </article>


<!-- recommended not necessary for hbec
    <%= render :partial => "/lessons/recommended" %>
-->
    <p class="adjust">Most Recent Lessons</p>
    <ul class="cat_thumbnails plugin-filter-elements portfolio-items" id="items">
      <% if @lessons.present? %>
          <% @lessons.each do |lesson| %>
              <li class="col-sm-4 lessonpad mix illustration li-back">
                <a href="<%= "#{lesson_path(lesson)}" %>">
                  <!-- Portfolio image -->
                  <% avatar = (lesson.image.present? ? "#{lesson.image.url}" : "/assets/placeholder_01.png") %>
                  <img src="<%= avatar %>" alt="Treble" class="recent-lessons-icon">

                  <!-- Portfolio name, activated on hover -->
                  <h3 align="center" class="category-text"><%= lesson.title %></h3>
                </a>
                <%= render "latest_lessons", :lesson => lesson %>
              </li>

          <% end %>
      <% else %>
          <%
             category_or_subcategory_name = ""
             category_or_subcategory_name = " '#{@lesson_category.name}' " if @lesson_category.present?
             category_or_subcategory_name = " '#{@lesson_subcategory.name}' " if @lesson_subcategory.present?
          %>
          <h3 class="error"> No <%= category_or_subcategory_name %> from custom Lessons were found</h3>
      <% end %>

    </ul>
    <% if @lessons.present? && @current_page.to_i < @max_pages.to_i %>
        <div class="center loadmore">
          <button class="btn btn-success load_more" onclick="load_more('/lessons', 'lessons')">Load More</button>
        </div>
    <% end %>



    <% if @categories.present? %>
        <p class="adjust">Choose a Category for Lessons</p>
        <ul class="cat_thumbnails plugin-filter-elements portfolio-items" id="">
          <% @categories.each do |cat| %>
              <li class="category-li col-sm-4 subpad  mix illustration <%= cat.slag %> ">

                <% link = cat.lesson_sub_categories.present? ? "/home/sub_categories?id=#{cat.id}" : " #{lessons_url(:lesson_category_id => cat.id)}" %>

                <a href="<%= link %>">
                  <!-- Portfolio image -->
                  <% avatar = (cat.avatar.present? ? "#{cat.avatar.url}" : "/assets/placeholder_01.png") %>
                  <img src="<%= avatar %>" class="choose-category-icon">

                  <!-- Portfolio name, activated on hover -->
                  <h3 align="center" class="category-text"><%= cat.name %></h3>
                </a>
                <br>
              </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
    <% end %>

    <% if  @categories.present? && LessonCategory.all.count > 5 %>
        <div class="center">
          <button class="btn btn-success load_more" onclick="window.location.href = '/home/categories'">Load More
          </button>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    </article>


  </div>
</div>
<%= hidden_field_tag :total_pages, @toal_pages %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :current_page, @current_page %>
```

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out,  my problem had to do with losing the instance variables between post and get,  so fixed this by ensuring my custom controller method is executed every time the page reloads,  all I had to add was:

before_filter :custom

this ensures that as the guest navigates the lessons are refreshed.

Might not be the right way,  however, it achieves the effect I desire,  welcome any additional advise

thanks